# php - compare between the indexes of one array and the values of another array

Tags: php

I have a project in which I should upload multiple images to the web page with image removal option.

So it's obvious when I upload images using input with name of images and remove some uploaded images the removed images don't be removed from the input and when I submit the form all images are inserted into database even removed images ..

Now when ever I remove an image from web page I append a hidden input with name of `deletedImg[]` inside my form : this input will have the index of removed image (eg. first image removed then the input with name `deletedImg[]` will have the value of 0,second image removed then another input with name deletedImg[] will have the value of 1 .. and so on)

These values are the indexes of removed images and I want to ignore them when I upload the images when the form is submitted .. how can I achieve this?

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
    $deleted = $_POST['deletedImg']; //This is the array containing the deleted image indexes

    foreach($_FILES['images']['name'] as $key=>$val)
    { 
        $nameOfImage = basename($_FILES['images']['name'][$key]);
        $avatarTempName = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'][$key];
        // List of allowed image extensions
        $avatarAllowedExtension = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png", "gif");

        // Get avatar extension
        $avatarExtension = strtolower(end(explode('.', $nameOfImage)));

        if(in_array($avatarExtension, $avatarAllowedExtension))
        {
            $postImage = rand(0, 10000000000) . '_' . $nameOfImage;

            // Move image into Covers folder
            move_uploaded_file($avatarTempName, "Uploads\Posts\\" . $postImage);

            // Insert image into database
            $stmt = $con->prepare("insert into postImages (ID , userId , postID , postImg) values (DEFAULT , :userId, (select max(ID)from post) , :postImg)");
            $stmt-> execute(array(
                'userId' => $_SESSION['ID'],
                'postImg' => $postImage
            ));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the values of this array you can use this:

```
$deleted = array_values($_POST['deletedImg']);
```

You then can use `in_array($val, $deleted)` to check of one of the posted imagename exists in the deleted array.

Comment: I've tried to do it but the images are not uploading or inserted into database